# CSS not getting applied to a contact form in Drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu

http://jsfiddle.net/P73rC/2/

I am trying to apply css to the contact form at contact us `li`, for example i m accessing the input type submit button but no css is getting applied to it in fact i cant access any of the form input to apply css to it.Specially the Input type Submit button is ignoring all of the css.

what mistake am i making all of the form css starts afterline 172 in the css block at the 
fiddle

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in your style `input [type="submit"]` which means all submits inside another `input`.

Correct rule is `input[type="submit"]`